# Insert a dropdown menu on a web page using Tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown, tampermonkey

I am looking for a simple tampermonkey script to insert a dropdown menu right after an element in one of the internal portals in my organization. Can someone please give me a hand with a script that can inject a dropdown menu in a web page. I think I can tweak it from there to suit my requirements.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include code, a minimal example..

Answer (score 0):

If you have an id to the element you want, just do this:

```
var menu = document.createElement('select');
var option1 = document.createElement('option');
option1.innerText = 'option 1 text';
menu.appendChild(option1);
...


document.getElementById('whatever').appendChild(menu);
```